# puppet-archive not working as expected

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet-archive to download my file from a repository

```
archive { "/usrdata/archive/${tomcat::jreversion}":
  ensure       => present,
  extract      => true,
  extract_path => '/usrdata/apps/java/',
  source       => $tomcat::params::jredownloadpath,
  creates      => "/usrdata/apps/java/${tomcat::jdkversion}",
}
```

But I get the following error on puppet run -:

> Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of
>   nil into String at 26:/etc/puppet/modules/tomcat/manifests/javaora.pp
>   Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: no implicit conversion of
>   nil into String at 26:/etc/puppet/modules/tomcat/manifests/javaora.pp
>   Wrapped exception: no implicit conversion of nil into String Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Javaora/Archive[/usrdata/archive/jre-7]/ensure:
>   change from absent to present failed: Could not set 'present' on
>   ensure: no implicit conversion of nil into String at
>   26:/etc/puppet/modules/tomcat/manifests/javaora.pp

I am able to download the file when I use `wget` on the same machine.

I am using puppet 3.8.7

Comment: @MattSchuchard: the "}" (closing curly brace). Below `creates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You local `$tomcat::params::jredownloadpath` is undefined. Ensure it is defined and correct.

Comment: Had figured that out and raised a request for meaningful error with the developer team.